# Calculating time difference between two rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate the time difference between two rows using `shift()`, but I get an unexpected error. I may be missing something obvious

```
df['Delta'] = (df.index - df.index.shift(1))
```

This statement produces a `ValueError:  Cannot shift with no offset`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

- If you have a DatetimeIndex, the `shift` shifts your data with a period of time. If your index has no frequency, you have to provide that to the shift method with the `freq` keyword (eg `freq='s'` to shift the data one second)
- You cannot substract two index objects like that, as this gives you a difference set operation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#set-operations-on-index-objects

If you just want the difference between two consecutive values in the index, you can use the `diff` method (of a Series, a bit easier than shift and substract):

```
df['index_col'] = df.index
df['Delta'] = df['index_col'].diff()
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps confusingly, pre-1.0 [Series.shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [Index.shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.shift.html) used to not exactly do the same thing, the latter only being meaningfully defined for TimesSeries.  Probably easiest to add your index as a column.

```
df['index_col'] = df.index
df['Delta']=(df['index_col'] - df['index_col'].shift(1))
```