# check if each user has consecutive dates in a python 3 pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Imagine there is a dataframe:

```
   id        date  balance_total  transaction_total
0   1  01/01/2019          102.0               -1.0
1   1  01/02/2019          100.0               -2.0
2   1  01/03/2019          100.0                NaN
3   1  01/04/2019          100.0                NaN
4   1  01/05/2019           96.0               -4.0
5   2  01/01/2019          200.0               -2.0
6   2  01/02/2019          100.0               -2.0
7   2  01/04/2019          100.0                NaN
8   2  01/05/2019           96.0               -4.0
```

here is the create dataframe command:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

users=pd.DataFrame(
                [
                {'id':1,'date':'01/01/2019', 'transaction_total':-1, 'balance_total':102},
                {'id':1,'date':'01/02/2019', 'transaction_total':-2, 'balance_total':100},
                {'id':1,'date':'01/03/2019', 'transaction_total':np.nan, 'balance_total':100},
                {'id':1,'date':'01/04/2019', 'transaction_total':np.nan, 'balance_total':100},
                {'id':1,'date':'01/05/2019', 'transaction_total':-4, 'balance_total':np.nan},
                {'id':2,'date':'01/01/2019', 'transaction_total':-2, 'balance_total':200},
                {'id':2,'date':'01/02/2019', 'transaction_total':-2, 'balance_total':100},
                {'id':2,'date':'01/04/2019', 'transaction_total':np.nan, 'balance_total':100},
                {'id':2,'date':'01/05/2019', 'transaction_total':-4, 'balance_total':96}  
                ]
                )
```

How could I check if each id has consecutive dates or not? I use the 
"shift" idea here but it doesn't seem to work:

[Calculating time difference between two rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328125/calculating-time-difference-between-two-rows/25328382#25328382)

```
df['index_col'] = df.index

for id in df['id'].unique():

    # create an empty QA dataframe

    column_names = ["Delta"]
    df_qa = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

    df_qa['Delta']=(df['index_col'] - df['index_col'].shift(1))

    if (df_qa['Delta'].iloc[1:] != 1).any() is True:

        print('id ' + id +' might have non-consecutive dates')

        # doesn't print any account => Each Customer's Daily Balance has Consecutive Dates
    break
```

Ideal output:

```
it should print id 2 might have non-consecutive dates
```

Thank you!

Comment: A true [mcve] in a pandas question... Really deserves +1 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `diff`:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"],format="%m/%d/%Y")

df["difference"] = df.groupby("id")["date"].diff()

print (df.loc[df["difference"]>pd.Timedelta(1, unit="d")])

#
   id       date  transaction_total  balance_total difference
7   2 2019-01-04                NaN          100.0     2 days
```

Comment: this solution works even if the id is uuid and more readable!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html), compre by greatee like `1` and filter only `id` column by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
users['date'] = pd.to_datetime(users['date'])

i = users.loc[users.groupby('id')['date'].diff().dt.days.gt(1), 'id'].tolist()
print (i)
[2]

for val in i:
    print( f'id {val} might have non-consecutive dates')
id 2 might have non-consecutive dates
```

Answer (score 1):

First step is to parse `date`:

`users['date'] = pd.to_datetime(users.date)`.

Then add a shifted column on the id and date columns:

```
users['id_shifted'] = users.id.shift(1)
users['date_shifted'] = users.date.shift(1)
```

The difference between `date` and `date_shifted` columns is of interest:

`>>> users.date - users.date_shifted`

```
0       NaT
1    1 days
2    1 days
3    1 days
4    1 days
5   -4 days
6    1 days
7    2 days
8    1 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

You can now query the DataFrame for what you want:

`users[(users.id_shifted == users.id) & (users.date_shifted - users.date != np.timedelta64(days=1))]`

That is, consecutive lines of the same user with a date difference != 1 day.

This solution does assume the data is sorted by (id, date).

Comment: Thank you! I got an error of ```ValueError: cannot set a Timedelta with a non-timedelta``` in the last line ```users[(users.id_shifted == users.id) & (users.date_shifted - users.date != np.timedelta64(days=1))]``` still trying to figure it out

Comment: i see what happened. the real id here is uuid instead of integers. Any thoughts? @Freek Wiekmeijer

Comment: We only do two things with the `id` column: shift (which is insensitive to the dtype) and compare `id == id_shifted` (which is also dtype insensitive problem because the two columns have the same dtype)